# SqlAlchemy Self-Referencing Bulk insert foreign key constrain

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following Model

```py
class Nodes(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'nodes'
  uid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
  category_id = Column(String)
  next_id = Column(String,ForeignKey('nodes.uid',name='nextrelation'))
  next_relation = relationship('Nodes', remote_side=[uid], backref='prev', foreign_keys=[next_id])
  text = Column(String)
  created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
```

```py
def bulk_insert(nodes_data:list):
  return db.bulk_insert_mappings(Nodes,nodes_data)
```

When I execute `db.bulk_insert_mappings(Nodes,nodes_data)` I get an error stating that the `Key (next_id)=(xxxx) is not present in table`.

Is it not possible to do bulk insertion for self-referencing tables?

Right now the only way I am bypassing it is inserting with `next_id` as `null` and later on running a loop to to update each nodes

Or maybe the question is also should I even self-reference? or keep it without any relation?